# Only Printing one sheet of table Html Css

Tags: html, css

Im working on a project for a family friend and I have run into an issue while printing a table it tunicates all the data but one page. This seems to be the case in all the browsers that i have tried (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) The Table is set up in a div (table-stuff in the example code) that has the overflow set to auto then the print css sets the overflow to visible (This is what i have found to do when searching for the problem) and hides all the other elements with a no-print class. Its set up as the following

```
    <main> 
      <div class='grid'> 
       <div class='contents'> 
        <div class='table-stuff>
           <table> Lots of data in table</table> 
        </div>
       </div> 
      </div>
     </main>
```

Print CSS:

```
 .no-print {
    display: none !important;
  }

 .table-stuff {
    overflow: visible !important;
    float: none !important;
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated and if any other info is needed I'd be happy to provide. Thank You in advance

So I was able to get it to print correctly and it was because of google material design lite causing the issue. I still am trying to find what style was causing the issue though.

Comment: Can you provide a functional html code ?

Comment: Yes Although It has a lot of php because it is pulling the data from a sql database using php so i just short handed the structure of it

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra what exactly is `functional html code` ?

Comment: @Pogrindis the initial post had html code that a browser wouldn't recognize.

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra ah i see now!

Comment: @Pogrindis Yeah I had Quickly typed it not thinking I have fixed it so it is Functional now. After researching, this is the page that I had found (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/851-fixing-divs-that-cause-content-truncation-when-printing.htm) But to no avail it didnt fix the issue.

Comment: @Astrea What do you mean by printing? save as a pdf?

Comment: `<style> main * {   overflow: visible !important;  float: none !important; } </style>` place this before `</head>`

Comment: @zer00ne This does not fix the issue exactly the same result Thanks for the help though

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra Yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a `@media` in your css file. I would do something similar like this:

```
@media print {
    table.no-print {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not having an issue with not wanting the table there It is not printing all of the data from the table only one page this would cause my table to not be printed.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot? What do you mean with one page? are the tables being paginated?